# How to configure MUI alert to honor new line in its message?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is my code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Alert from "@mui/material/Alert";
import AlertTitle from "@mui/material/AlertTitle";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";

export default function DescriptionAlerts() {
  const message =
    "This is a message \n This message has Enter in it \n MUI Alert does not honor the Enter \n I can not use dangerouslySetInnerHTML \n Because this message contains <h1>Hi</h1> in it \n And I want to show that HTML string to my user \n I don't want to render that HTML";
  return (
    <Stack sx={{ width: "100%" }} spacing={2}>
      <Alert severity="error">
        <AlertTitle>Error</AlertTitle>
        {message}
      </Alert>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

And here is a live [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-bird-lirtd6?file=/demo.tsx:0-683) showing it in action.

I have a message that I receive from the API. This message contains HTML that needs to be shown to the user as HTML code, without being rendered. Thus AMAIK I can't use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

However, it has some new line characters in it. How can I tell MUI Alert to honor these new lines?

Answer (score 9):

You have to add style `white-space: pre-line;` to `Alert`.

```
<Alert severity="error" sx={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line' }}>
    {message}
</Alert>
```